# Contour Map Charting Package for Windows 8

Tags: windows, charts

I am looking for a charting package to draw simple contour maps in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8 from a VB.Net or a C# application; something like this:-

[image: example map] <sup>example map (click for larger variant)</sup>

I am looking form something simple to code up, and which need not have any particularly glorious features; being able to draw the chart above from an array of values will be quite sufficient. The ability to draw on web pages would be nice but working on a forms application is all that is necessary.

The chart above was drawn with Olectra Chart; this is now defunct. I am in the process of evaluating its replacement, ComponentOne Studio, but that package is proving rather recalcitrant, so would appreciate any other suggestions.